# Vuejs v-for add tag attribute or event listener depending on some condition

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have an array of objects on which I loop over in my template.

```html
<div v-for="(list, idx) in collection" :key="list.id">
    <misc v-if="!idx" :is-master="!idx" :selection="list" v-on:report="onSelectionReport"></misc>
    <misc v-else :is-master="!idx" :selection="list"></misc>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are two "misc" tags. The only reason for this is that I only want the "report" event to bubble up from a single instance.

This works, though is there a way to save a v-if/v-else construct in a such case? (which would result in a single misc tag here).

Thank you.

Comment: Pass `idx` as a prop and do if else logic in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an inline event handler to check the value of `idx`:

```html
<div v-for="(list, idx) in collection" :key="list.id">
    <misc :is-master="!idx" :selection="list" v-on:report="arg => idx || onSelectionReport(arg)"></misc>
</div>
```

However, as @Lawrence Cherone suggested, it might be cleaner to do this logic inside the component - especially since you're passing `idx` as a property (via `is-master`) anyways.

Comment: I thought about this but there will be as much event handlers in memory as there are <misc> instances and ideally I wanted to avoid this. If there is no  better alternative I will choose your answer as the solution. Thank you.